# Docker and WSL error: UNAUTHORIZED

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Recently started to use Docker in Windows because that's the enviroument where I work. I don't have any problem connecting WSL with Windows Docker an using it for first instance.

After reboot my laptop the problems cames to me. When I'm trying to create an image I get the next error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers).
```

Is so weird beacause if uninstall windows docker and reinstall it, everything works but if reboot or shut down my laptop, the problem comes again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like DNS resolve issues about Docker registry.

Sometimes DNS on DHCP information or your network settings makes this trouble on windows.

Try to change DNS options from `Automatic` to `Fixed` `GoogleDNS(8.8.8.8)` on Docker for Windows settings.

Please refer this screenshot.
[Fixed DNS Settings on Docker for windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUfFq.jpg)
[image]